# How can we update data in array so that when we move data from one array to another its order gets adjusted according to stage in which it is dropped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a Planning board for a team where it contains some stages and each stage contains some tasks to perform. A task can be drag and drop to other stages. It is an order-based board. If a user drag and drop any task to other stages then its order will adjust as per in dropped stage order. So that I can get the task in increasing sorting order.
Let say there are 2 stages and each stage contains 2 tasks and each stage task order is 1 and 2. When the user drags a task (let say order 1) from the first stage and drops it in between the tasks of second stage i.e in between both the task then the order of the second stage should get adjusted. so that I can get the order as 1, 2, 3. As task with order 1 remain the same place and task with order 2 will increase the order to 3 and the task that is shifted to second from first will get order 2.
In the end, I can get tasks in order wise. I can change the model if necessary so that I can write performance in mongodb.

**PLAN MODEL in MONGODB**

```
const planSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
     required: [true, 'Plan title is required for plan'],
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    required: [true, 'Plan creator is required'],
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  stages: [{ id: String, name: String, tasks: [task: String, order: Number]}],
});
```

Comment: What is the behavior you are currently seeing?

Comment: What I have done is when creating a task I'm assigining the order length of array + 1.  how could I assign the order as per dropped stage and update all other task below that dropped task.

Comment: So are you just looking for how to insert something into a Javascript array at a specific index?

Comment: I am looking how can we insert element in MongoDB of array type at a specific location so that element after that order is increased by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check `position` operator. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) is the reference